# asset_path 404 Rails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, video

I'm currently having a little trouble installing and using https://github.com/VodkaBears/Vide in my rails application.

```
path/
├── to/
│   ├── video.mp4
│   ├── video.ogv
│   ├── video.webm
│   └── video.jpg
```

As you can see it hunts for files within a certain path.

So trying the following

```
<div class="container-fluid unlogged"  data-vide-bg="<%= asset_path('/assets/videos/video') %>" data-vide-options="loop: false, muted: false, position: 0% 0%">
```

But returns multiple errors

> GET http://localhost:5000/assets/videos/video.jpg 404 (Not Found)
>
> GET http://localhost:5000/assets/videos/video.mp4 404 (Not Found)

Any help would be brilliant,

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to set:

```
config.serve_static_assets = true
```

in the production.rb file. 
Also check out: 
https://github.com/heroku/rails_serve_static_assets

Answer (score 0):

The usual use case for videos is to put them in to public directory, as they don't require any processing like compression and minification.
So I would suggest you to put your video into `/public` and use [video_path](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/AssetUrlHelper.html#method-i-video_url) helper method.

Comment: I'm currently using heroku which would hate that - can I store them in S3 and load from there?

Comment: Yes, just use then `video_url` helper or configure the `config.action_controller.asset_host = "http://YOUR_BUCKET.s3.amazonaws.com"` to store all of your assets at S3.

Comment: Unfortunately the plugin isn't looking for the helper method, it wants a folder where it can go and hunt for the assets -

"data-vide-bg="path/to/video"

Comment: Then forget about any helpers and just point to public/s3 folder as is.